# SetWinEventHook callback does not work when app is a service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, hook, keyboard-events

I have an app made in .NET 4.0 that hooks on win events and uses a callback to catch the window events like so:

```
    //import the methos from the dll
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(int eventMin, int eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventProc lpfnWinEventProc, int idProcess, int idThread, int dwflags);
    //declare a callback
    public static WinEventProc _winEventProc = new WinEventProc(WindowEventCallback);
    //pass this callback to SetWinEventHook
    SetWinEventHook(
            EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, // eventMin
            EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, // eventMax
            IntPtr.Zero,             // hmodWinEventProc
            _winEventProc,
            0,                       // idProcess
            0,                       // idThread
            WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);
   //define somthing in callback
   private static void WindowEventCallback(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr      hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
    {
        Logger.Instance.Write("WindowEventCallback");
    }
    //the loop that reads the messages
     while (true)
        {
            if (PeekMessage(out msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                if (msg.Message == WM_QUIT)
                    break;
                TranslateMessage(ref msg);
                DispatchMessage(ref msg);
            }
        }
```

This code works perfectly when the app is configured as a console app.
But I want it to run as a service, so I change a bit the loop because we cannot have a continuous loop in OnStart method of the service. So I made a timer that reads messages at a 50 ms interval like so:

```
MSG msg;
        if (PeekMessage(out msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(ref msg);
            DispatchMessage(ref msg);
        }
//
```

I also changed the entire app, I created a new project as a window Service created a installer for the service and made it run. It runs ok as a service but I don't get events notifications.
My assumption is that there is some issues with the windows rights when running an app as a service.

The app is made on Win7 64 with Visual Studio 2010 .NET 4.0

Do you have any idea on why I don't catch the event notifications?

Thank you

Comment: `The client thread that calls SetWinEventHook must have a message loop in order to receive events.` Create thread in OnStart. Inside thread function call SetWinEventHook and then execute endless event loop. In OnStop use PostQuitMessage to stop the thread.

Comment: The documentation doesn't seem to say, but presumably such a hook is limited to the same session as the process.  That means a hook in a service will only get events from other services, not from programs running in a user's session.

Comment: I redo the code and started a thread in onStart service, I implemented a while loop to read messages. In the same thread I also hooked to all win events. On 20-30% of the tests I get some events but not active windows events as I am interested in.

Comment: Harry Johnson can you explain a bit more this issue I did not get it 100%. Thx

Comment: After some intensive research I found out that I cannot catch window events in a service application as we do in a console application because the service application runs in a different window station. We can catch events, but the events are not events from the current station so we cannot get active window as I needed or any other events that happen in out window station.